# incrementation of a variable without action

Tags: flutter, list, dart, animation, increment

i'm using animatedSwitcher of flutter , to animate my list of widget , but the thing is i want to show the next widget of the list without pressing any button , like after a duration , but i couldn't figure out how , so im seeking for any help here , this is my code

```
 Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(
          children: [
           
            AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
                return ScaleTransition(scale: animation, child: child);
              },
              child: Text(
                widget.aya[i].text,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you `FutureBuilder` and add your desired duration after that you want the next widget to show and return it.

Like below code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
        body: FutureBuilder<Widget>(
          future: _futureFunction(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return snapshot.data ?? const SizedBox.shrink();
            }
            return Container(
              color: Colors.indigoAccent,
            );
          },
        ));
  }

  Future<Widget> _futureFunction() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
    );
  }
}
```

Here i'm returning `FutureBuilder` from scaffold body and passed a `_futureFunction()` whose returning a container after 5 seconds till that seconds a container with indigoAccent colour will be shown and after a container returned from function will be visible.

This whole thing will be done without any action.

But in basic application you can use the FutureBuilder cause it's a simple solution but i don't suggest using in the complex application cause the FutureBuilder build itself on every changing state, For that you should use state management tools like Bloc or Cubits.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use a Timer.

```
  int currentIndex = 0;
  Timer? timer;

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   // Start the timer to switch automatically every 2seconds
   timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (_) {
   setState(() {
       currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % widget.aya.length;
        });
   });
 }
```

With this setup, the widgets will automatically switch every 3 seconds, providing the desired behavior without needing to press any buttons.